# Using Burpsuite over a VPN

Tags: android, proxy, vpn

There is a application that only works over a VPN and I need to intercept it's traffic in my burpsuite. The Burp is in my Host PC and the application is in Android emulator in the same PC but everytime I connect the VPN, even when the proxy is enabled, Burp catch no traffic and the android emulator loads everything fine. How to get my burp catch the traffic while using the VPN simultaneously in the emulator.

I tries split tunneling and tried using vpn in the host PC. I am using nordvpn and Nox emulator.

Comment: If the VPN is active this like a new network adapter that is used for all traffic. The VPN ignores the configured proxy and so you don't capture anything. Even if it would use your configured proxy this would only redirect the VPN traffic through the proxy not the app traffic protected/tunneled inside the VPN connection. Note that the emulated Android system and the host PC are two distinct machines even if they are executed on the same PC. That is the purpose of a virtual system.